# OnCollisionEnter() not working when two GameObjects collide

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

This code here doesn't work, I don't get any errors, but the scripts doesn't print "End" in the console when my player hits something, here's the code:

```cs
using UnityEngine;

public class GameManager : MonoBehaviour
{
    public void End(){
        Debug.Log("End");
    }
}
```

and on another script:

```cs
using UnityEngine;

public class PlayerCollision3 : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Move movement;

    void OnCollisionEnter (Collision collisionInfo) {

        if (collisionInfo.collider.tag == "obsik"){

            movement.enabled = false;
            FindObjectOfType<GameManager>().End();
        
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure it hit something tagged correctly?

Comment: Also both objects have colliders and at least one has a Rigidbody?